# Агрегация, агрегаты и композиция с++

Tags: c++, агрегация, композиция

Я довольно сильно запутался с терминами, поэтому не могли бы вы мне пожалуйста разъяснить что да как. Агрегация и композиция, насколько я понял, это способы отношений между классами. Но как тогда называются классы, которые связаны этими способами - композитные и агрегатные? Посмотрев в интернете, я увидел, что у агрегатных классов (их насколько я понял называют агрегатами) несколько другое определение и у меня возникает вопрос: связанно ли оно как-нибудь с понятием агрегации? А определение композитных классов я вообще не нашёл и я сомневаюсь, что так вообще можно говорить. Объясните пожалуйста, что к чему

Comment: Классы никак не называются. Агрегация и композиция - это название отношений между классами. В С++ есть агрегатные типы (и соотв. трейт std::is_aggregate), но их название не происходит от отношений между классами.